# What is mybatis or ibatis like implementation in laravel or php?

Tags: php, laravel

I have worked with mybatis in Java and Spring and really like the way we have a clean separation of queries from code and the dynamic query feature.
I was wondering if we have something similar in laravel framework (php) or in php.

I am not looking at laravel orm.
The closet was [pbatis](https://code.google.com/p/pbatis/) but it is ready only and does not seem to be active.

Comment: I haven't used MyBatis or iBATIS, but seeing what you're after, I think you might be out of luck with that in the PHP realm. There is [SQLMap](http://www.pradosoft.com/demos/sqlmap/) which is based on iBATIS.NET, but it lacks Dynamic SQL and the rest of it might not have the syntax you're probably expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this: https://github.com/kings36503/sqlTemplate

A powerful PHP SQL template composer library which can significantly reduce the number and complexity of the SQL statement in the project. Reference to the ibatis implementation.